# How to draw an average column in Google Charts Bar Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, average

I am trying to create a GoogleCharts **Bar Chart** with CategoryFilters which also shows the **average** of each category/group. How do I calculate and show an additional bar/column of the average?

Something like this (example) --> https://ibb.co/wQksgGN

I already tried using [trendlines](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/trendlines) in the Chart options part, but they are only lines, not bars/columns, and it doesn't seem to work with my code.

```
trendlines: { 3: {}},
```

Here all my code so far --> https://jsfiddle.net/tototatutu/ktwr5jap/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you need to calculate the average before the charts are drawn,
you won't be able to use the dashboard / bind functionality.

instead, you will need to perform the average calculation and draw the charts,
during the controls' state change event.

first we assign the data table to the controls, add the event listener, and draw them.

```
// Define category pickers for 'KPI', 'Peer Group'
var kpiPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
  containerId: 'control1',
  dataTable: data,               // <-- add data table
  options: {
    filterColumnLabel: 'KPI',
    ui: {
      labelStacking: 'vertical',
      allowTyping: false,
      allowMultiple: false,
      caption: 'Choose KPI',
      sortValues: true,
      allowNone: false
  }}
});

var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
  controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
  containerId: 'control2',
  dataTable: data,               // <-- add data table
  options: {
    filterColumnLabel: 'Peer Group',
    ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        caption: 'Choose Peer Group',
        sortValues: true,
        allowNone: false
    }}
});

// Add state change event listeners
google.visualization.events.addListener(kpiPicker, 'statechange', stateChange);
google.visualization.events.addListener(regionPicker, 'statechange', stateChange);

// Draw controls
kpiPicker.draw();
regionPicker.draw();
```

next, during the state change event, we create a data view and filter the data based on the selected categories.

```
// Build data view, filter based on category filters
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(view.getFilteredRows([{
  column: 0,
  value: kpiPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]
}, {
  column: 1,
  value: regionPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]
}]));
```

then use the `group` method to find the average of the view.

```
// Group data, calculate average
var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
  view,
  [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Average';}}],
  [{
    column: 3,
    type: 'number',
    label: 'Average',
    aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg
  }]
);
```

then we convert the data view back to a data table, add the average row, and sort.

```
// Convert view to data table, add average row, sort
view = view.toDataTable();
view.addRow([kpiPicker.getState().selectedValues[0], regionPicker.getState().selectedValues[0], 'Peer Group Average', groupData.getValue(0, 1), '#757575']);
view.sort({column: 3, desc: true});
```

afterwards, we assign the data view to the charts and draw...

```
// Draw charts
barChart.setDataTable(view);
table.setDataTable(view);
barChart.draw();
table.draw();
```

see following working snippet for a full example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls']
}).then(function () {
  // Prepare the data
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['KPI', 'Peer Group', 'Products', 'Amount', { role: 'style' }],
    ['KPI 1', 'EMEA', 'Product A', 4, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 1', 'EMEA', 'Product B', 6, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 1', 'EMEA', 'Product C', 2, '#F46B1B'],
    ['KPI 1', 'Americas', 'Product A', 3, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 1', 'Americas', 'Product B', 8, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 1', 'Americas', 'Product C', 7, '#F46B1B'],
    ['KPI 2', 'EMEA', 'Product A', 9, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 2', 'EMEA', 'Product B', 1, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 2', 'EMEA', 'Product C', 4, '#F46B1B'],
    ['KPI 2', 'Americas', 'Product A', 4, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 2', 'Americas', 'Product B', 6, '#003E7D'],
    ['KPI 2', 'Americas', 'Product C', 7, '#F46B1B']
  ]);

  // Define category pickers for 'KPI', 'Peer Group'
  var kpiPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control1',
    dataTable: data,               // <-- add data table
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'KPI',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        caption: 'Choose KPI',
        sortValues: true,
        allowNone: false
    }}
  });

  var regionPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control2',
    dataTable: data,               // <-- add data table
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Peer Group',
      ui: {
          labelStacking: 'vertical',
          allowTyping: false,
          allowMultiple: false,
          caption: 'Choose Peer Group',
          sortValues: true,
          allowNone: false
      }}
  });

  // Define a bar chart to show 'Amount' data
  var barChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'BarChart',
    containerId: 'chart1',
    options: {
      width: 480,
      height: 300,
      legend: 'none',
      bar: {
          groupWidth: '50%'
      },
      animation: {
          duration: 600,
      },
      hAxis: {
            minValue: 0,
            maxValue: 1,
            ticks: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
            gridlines: {
               color: '#F46B1B'
            },
            textStyle: {
               color: '#003E7D',
               fontSize: 15,
               fontName: 'Montserrat',
               bold: true,
            },
         },
      vAxis: {
               textStyle: {
                  fontName: 'Montserrat',
                  color: '#003E7D',
                  fontSize: 11,
                  bold: true
               },
            },
    },
    // Configure the barChart to use columns 2 (Products), 3 (Amount), and 4 (style/colors)
    'view': {'columns': [2, 3, 4]}
  });

  // Define a table.
  // The table shows whatever is selected by the category pickers. It's here
  // just for reference and debugging.
  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
      'width': '400px'
    },
    'view': {'columns': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
  });

  // Add state change event listeners
  google.visualization.events.addListener(kpiPicker, 'statechange', stateChange);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(regionPicker, 'statechange', stateChange);

  // Draw controls
  kpiPicker.draw();
  regionPicker.draw();

  // Draw charts
  stateChange();

  function stateChange() {
    // Build data view, filter based on category filters
    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setRows(view.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: kpiPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]
    }, {
      column: 1,
      value: regionPicker.getState().selectedValues[0]
    }]));

    // Group data, calculate average
    var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
      view,
      [{column: 0, type: 'string', modifier: function () {return 'Average';}}],
      [{
        column: 3,
        type: 'number',
        label: 'Average',
        aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg
      }]
    );

    // Convert view to data table, add average row, sort
    view = view.toDataTable();
    view.addRow([kpiPicker.getState().selectedValues[0], regionPicker.getState().selectedValues[0], 'Peer Group Average', groupData.getValue(0, 1), '#757575']);
    view.sort({column: 3, desc: true});

    // Draw charts
    barChart.setDataTable(view);
    table.setDataTable(view);
    barChart.draw();
    table.draw();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard">
  <table>
    <tr style='vertical-align: top'>
      <td style='width: 300px; font-size: 0.9em;'>
        <div id="control1" style='margin-top: 50px;'></div>
        <div id="control2" style='margin-top: 10px;'></div>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 600px;'>
        <div style="float: left; margin-top: 50px;" id="chart1"></div>
        <div style="float: left; margin-top: 50px;" id="chart2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

**NOTE:** `https://www.google.com/jsapi` should no longer be used to load google charts,
it is an **old** version.

`https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js` should be used instead.

this will only change the `load` statement.

see above snippet...

Comment: That's amazing – thank you very much @WhiteHat ! It works!

I am not too familiar with how the "google.visualization.data.group" method works – will try to read more about it. Just recently started with Google Charts and JavaScript in general :)